# Access SVN repository from outside local network

Tags: apache, http, svn, ubuntu-16.04

I set up an svn server on my Ubuntu 16.04 server as described in this article: https://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-server-on-ubuntu/

I am able to access it via http://LOCAL_IP_OF_SERVER/svn/myrepo

I also enabled port forwarding of port 80 to the mac address of my server in my router settings.

Yet, I am unable to access the svn via the server's external IP address. What am I missing?

EDIT: there only seem to be ipv6 related settings in my router. Could this be the issue?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It works when using IPv6. Seems to bei ISP related.